# I am confused on the last step of "differentiability implies continuity"

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am watching this [video](https://youtu.be/n_0XEaY1V0E) of the proof " differentiability implies continuity " for functions $ f: U\subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $, and I have doubts about the last step. In the proof it is concluded that $$ \lim_{t \to c } ~ (f(t) - f(c)) = 0 .$$ From here they use limit laws to rewrite the left side as a difference of limits. $$ \lim_{t \to c } f(t) - \lim_{t \to c }  f(c) = 0. $$ My question is, using the limit law is only valid provided we know apriori that $ \lim_{t \to c }f(t) $ and $ \lim_{t \to c } f(c) $ exist. It is easy to show that $ \lim_{t \to c } f(c) $ exists, since $\lim_{t \to c } f(c) = f(c)$, but I don't see where it is given in the hypothesis that $ \lim_{t \to c }f(t) $ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
$$
\lim_{t \to c} f(t) = \lim_{t \to c} ((f(t) - f(c)) + f(c)) \overset \bigstar = \lim_{t \to c} (f(t)- f(c)) + \lim_{t \to c} f(c) = 0 + f(c) = f(c),
$$ hence the limit exists. $\bigstar$ is the addition law of limits

Comment: The addition law of limits says that we must know the limits exist apriori. Specifically, $\lim_{x \to a } [f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x \to a } f(x) +  \lim_{x \to a } g(x)  $, provided  $ \lim_{x \to a } f(x) $ and $ \lim_{x \to a } g(x)$  exist. 

How do we know that $\lim_{t \to c} (f(t)- f(c))$ exists in your statement.  It seems we have to assume $\lim_{t \to c} f(t)$ exists.

Comment: @john Didn't you say that $\lim_{t\to c} (f(t ) - f(c)) = 0$ in your post? Did I read your post wrong? Confused…

Comment: @john Then I proved $\lim_{t\to c} f(t)$ exists in my answer, as long as you acknowledged the existence of $\lim_{t \to c} (f(t) - f(c))$. I didn't assume $f(t)$ has a limit beforehand at all. Unnecessary.

Comment: oh i see now . but that doesnt seem obvious to me , i wonder why many books skip this.

Comment: Because this is not necessary to spell out, or to make readers actively think about everything s/he writes instead of passively reading.

Answer (score 4):

If $\lim_{t \to c}[f(t) + g(t)]$ and $\lim_{t \to c} g(t)$ exist, then $\lim_{t \to c} f(t)$ exists too. Indeed, use the rule of difference that you are already aware of.

\begin{align}
f(t) &= [f(t) + g(t)] - g(t).
\end{align}

From the above, conclude that $\lim_{t \to c} f(t)$ does exist. Moreover, it equals $$\lim_{t \to c}[f(t) + g(t)] - \lim_{t \to c} g(t).$$

Comment: I think you have a typo, it should say "From the above, conclude that $\lim_{t \to c} f(t)$ does exist". Nice argument :)

Comment: @john: good catch, fixed now, thanks! :)

Comment: i find it strange, every proof of this statement includes the use of this limit law, without prior establishing the existence of the limits. [Here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html) and [here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a5e0e7376f3d9f29e44f5f8d9563db852877bd42), they both use implicitly this rule. $\lim_{t \to c}[f(t) - g(t)] = \lim_{t \to c} f(t)  - \lim_{t \to c} g(t) $

Comment: And also [here](https://math.jhu.edu/~brown/courses/f17/Documents/DiffImpliesCont.pdf), no mention of establishing the existence of the limits in the [last step](https://i.imgur.com/CtpWQ7E.png).

Comment: With what I have written, it becomes very simple to note the fact that to split $\lim_{t \to c}[f(t) - g(t)]$ as $\lim_{t \to c}f(t) - \lim_{t \to c}g(t)$, it suffices to only know that one of those limits exists, given that the limit of the difference does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above, from $ \lim_{t \to c } ~ (f(t) - f(c)) = 0 
$
we have $$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\lim_{t \to c } f(t) =  \lim_{t \to c } ~ [ (f(t) - f(c))  +f(c) ] 
\\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=  \lim_{t \to c } ~  (f(t) - f(c))  + \lim_{t \to c } f(c) 
\\~~~~~~~ = 0 + f(c)
$$